# https:// redirect to https://www in NGINX

Tags: redirects, 301-redirect, canonical-url, nginx

How do you redirect all non-www links to my website to `https://www.` I know that there are a lot of solutions for .htaccess but I haven't been able to find anything sufficient for nginx.

At the moment all I have is

```
##
# Redirect non-www to www
##
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name example.com; # add other domains separated by a space as necessary
     rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

which redirects:

```
example.com
www.example.com
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
```

to
`https://www.example.com` which is what I want, except that `https://example.com` doesn't redirect `https://www.example.com`

How do so how do I get `https://` to redirect to `https://www.`?

Comment: I would ask why you want to do that.  Most people want to get rid of the www.  If you recall, many years ago when writing a URL we would include the http(s):// at the beginning.  We learned to drop that.  Similarly we don't really need the www

Comment: @Steve It's just important for me to know how to do these things. I have been hacking away at this for a bit now and it is very frustrating because I can't get it to work. In addition to that, a lot of people I develop for want this on their websites and it easy to do when you have .htaccess. But this is the first time I'm not using WordPress.

Comment: @Steve To the contrary, there are legitimate reasons to use the www which is only a subdomain. Some places break their sites into many categories such as the one I was just at 'developers.google.com' and some prefer to keep assets in one area like 'images.mysite.com'.

Comment: I don't see a server listening on port 443 for https but your question is off topic here.

Comment: Rob, I fully understand the need for subdomains by some people and that www is simply another one.  However, while there might be "legitimate reasons" to use www, it is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rob port 443 is in my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file under server with `server_name example.com;`

Comment: @Steve Unnecessary to whom? www is the main entry point on the web for Google and Microsoft and any number of companies because that is their main business page. Other sub-domain names are used for other parts of their businesses. Using the www sub-domain is a well-thought out plan for them and not "unnecessary" at all.

Comment: @Rob but it isn't necessary for them to do that.  Their sites will work just as well if they chose to not use www for the main site just as any other subdomains will also work.  As you know, each is independent.

Comment: @Steve "Most people want to get rid of the www." - The www vs non-www debate is completely irrelevant to this question. (FWIW I'd wager that most people want the www subdomain! :) "might be "legitimate reasons" to use www, it is unnecessary" - if there is a "legitimate reason" then it's not unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my last answer using the "if" statement is not recommended in most cases, I came up with another solution which seems to be working perfectly.

What I did was create another server block with www in the `server_name` and had my other server blocks redirect to it.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ...
}

server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far what I came up with is a simple if statement under port 443 to check if the domain is non-www and then redirect to www

```
server {
# Enable HTTP/2
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name example.com;
if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

# Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
...
```

I'm no expert but I don't think this is the best solution because it will be doing an `if` statement for every request if I'm right?